# Java Generics, what to return instead of -1

Tags: java, generics

I am working on a SortedLinkedList or my class. We have to change a DoubleSortedLinkedList Class into a generic SortedLinkedList Class. I am implementing a remove method which is supposed to be given a position in the list and will remove the index given and return the value of that node.

Here is the code given:

```
public double remove(int givenPosition)
{
    double dataToReturn;
    if (givenPosition < 0 || givenPosition >= manyNodes)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (givenPosition == 0)
    {
        dataToReturn = head.getData();
        head = head.getLink();
    }
    else
    {
        DoubleNode previous = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition - 1; i++)
        {
            previous = previous.getLink();
        }
        DoubleNode oneToDelete = previous.getLink();
        dataToReturn = oneToDelete.getData();
        previous.setLink(oneToDelete.getLink());
        oneToDelete.setLink(null);
    }
    manyNodes--;
    return dataToReturn;
}
```

Here is the code I have once I have tried to change it to a generic class

```
public T remove(int givenPosition)
{
    T dataToReturn;
    if (givenPosition < 0 || givenPosition >= manyNodes)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (givenPosition == 0)
    {
        dataToReturn = head.getData();
        head = head.getLink();
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> previous = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition - 1; i++)
        {
            previous = previous.getLink();
        }
        Node<T> oneToDelete = previous.getLink();
        dataToReturn = oneToDelete.getData();
        previous.setLink(oneToDelete.getLink());
        oneToDelete.setLink(null);
    }
    manyNodes--;
    return dataToReturn;
}
```

My biggest issue is here is that when the given index is outside the range of the list or if the list is empty the method returned -1, but now that the class is a generic method I can't turn a literal -1 so I'm curious what I can return now instead of -1.

Comment: You could throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

**As an opinion**: it depends on the concrete situation. I consider this question in a more abstract view, without digging into the details: *why* do you return `-1`.

Say, in the simplified, more general case you had:

```
public double someOperation(int someArg) {
    if (certainConditionSatisfied()) {
       return -1;
    }
    // ...
}
```

and now it has to be converted into the new interface

```
public T someOperation(int someArg) {
    if (certainConditionSatisfied()) {
       return ????
    }
  // ...
}
```

In this case my general answer is:

Since `-1` was a special case, in the new implementation you can freely return `null`.

Of course, the corresponding code which use this method, needs to be changed as well to properly handle `null` instead of `-1`.

---

However, in your particular case, I tend to agree with @JohnnyMopp, who suggested in the commentary throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

Comment: Returning ``null`` is not particularly wrong, but throwing an ``IndexOutOfBoundsException`` as @johnny-mopp suggests is definitely more recommendable. Your SortedLinkList may be able to contain ``null``...

Comment: @LarsGendner it depends. If it is a regular situation, then catching an exception is less practical than compare expected "magic" value

Comment: The standard Java collection classes throw IndexOutOfBoundsException, so that should be the first choice. Though it is possible I can't see that removing missing elements would be a very common situation.

Comment: @andremoniy I don't want this to become an opinion discussion, and I know there are people who do not like Exceptions. Since the question was not about maintainability and software lifecycle, I restrain from objection ;-)

Comment: @LarsGendner I've tried to elaborate my question. I see this situation in a more general way.